# How can I display same date record through foreach loop from database in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, date, foreach

I want to display same date record from database using foreach loop.

Suppose I have below records in database.

```
Id          Name         created_date

1           XYZ         2020-12-08 13:24:20

2           YUZ         2020-12-04 11:40:04

3           TYZ         2020-12-03 11:54:58

4           SDD         2020-12-03 07:19:19
```

In Above table there are 2 records in same date '`2020-12-03`' , So I want to display same date record like below format in table.

```
Tuesday

 - 2020-12-08

Friday

 - 2020-12-04

Thursday

 - 2020-12-03
 - 2020-12-03
```

I have used below PHP script but it's not display that I need, It's only display separate 2 rows of same date.

```
<table>
<?
if(isset($getUsers) && !empty($getUsers)){
        foreach ($getUsers as $key => $value) {
            $date =$value['created_date'];

        $day ='';
        Switch(date('w',strtotime($date))){
                    Case 0:
                        $day= 'Sunday';
                        break;
                    Case 1:
                        $day= 'Monday';
                        break;
                    Case 2:
                        $day= 'Tuesday';
                        break;
                    Case 3:
                        $day= 'Wednesday';
                        break;
                    Case 4:
                        $day= 'Thursday';
                        break;
                    Case 5:
                        $day= 'Friday';
                        break;
                    default:
                        $day=  'Saturday';

                }
            ?>
          <thead>
            <tr >
              <th scope="col" colspan="4"><?php echo $day; ?></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>           
          <tr>
              <th scope="row" colspan="4"><?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['created_date'])) .'-'.  $value['name']; ?></th>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
            <?php
        }
     
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that in code? You can extend your query to give the weekday and sort by that.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, I already fetch record by weekly through DB query and now I only want same date record from that I fetched weekly data from DB

Comment: What have you tried to group the data properly?

Answer (score 0):

You should hashmap your days with the relevant data something like this:

```
    $daysMap = [];
    foreach ($getUsers as $key => $value) {
         $date =$value['created_date'];
    
         $day ='';
         Switch(date('w',strtotime($date))){
              Case 0:
                  $day= 'Sunday';
              break;
              Case 1:
                  $day= 'Monday';
              break;
              ...
        }
    
$daysMap[$day][] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['created_date'])) .'-'.  $value['name'];
    
    }
```

Later on, loop over the `$daysMap` and print each day with its dates inside.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a separate loop and create an array, using the day as key :

```
<table>
<?
if(isset($getUsers) && !empty($getUsers)){
    // first create the array to ensure the order of days will be respected
    $days = [
        'Sunday' => [],
        'Monday' => [],
        'Tuesday' => [],
        'Wednesday' => [],
        'Thursday' => [],
        'Friday' => [],
        'Saturday' => []
    ];

    // add the datas in the corresponding day in the array
    foreach ($getUsers as $value) {
        $date =$value['created_date'];
        $dayOfWeek = date('w',strtotime($date));
        $days[$dayOfWeek][] = $value;
    }

    // loop the array and display its content
    foreach ($days as $day => $values) {
        ?>
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th scope="col" colspan="4"><?php echo $day; ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            // Loop the sub array containing the values
            foreach ($values as $value) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" colspan="4"><?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['created_date'])) .'-'.  $value['name']; ?></th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</table>
```